# Sublime 3: Double clicking from find-results page no longer working

Tags: sublimetext3

Since build 3080, double clicking from the find-results page to jump to line-in-file directly is no longer working for me.

Has anyone else experienced or have a fix for this issue?

Comment: Please file an issue at the bug tracker [here](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core). Make sure you read the README on the main page for advice on filing the best issue possible.

Comment: For me it works double clicking the line that contains the result (but not double clicking the following and preceding lines the Find Results page shows). I'm using build 3083 on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this plugin was the culprit, removing it fixed the issue.

https://github.com/titoBouzout/FindResultsApplyChanges

Also, the author of the plugin states that this won't be fixed: https://github.com/titoBouzout/FindResultsApplyChanges/issues/9

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem too.